# how to join a table more than once when a table references different rows of that table

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, join, orm

I have a table which can have up to 3 references to another table.

here it is in my Django ORM

```
class CreatorCategories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class ContentCreatorUsers(models.Model):
    creatorcategory1 = models.ForeignKey(CreatorCategories, related_name='creatorcategory1', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    creatorcategory2 = models.ForeignKey(CreatorCategories, blank=True, related_name='creatorcategory2', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    creatorcategory3 = models.ForeignKey(CreatorCategories, blank=True, null=True, related_name='creatorcategory3', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    topbannerphotokey = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am running a sql query in a aws lambda (I have not added the select statements that will get the values for a categories name and icon)

```
SELECT id, creatordisplayname, contentcreatordisplaycardurl, creatorurlslug,
    currentmonitaryactioncount, isverifiedcontentcreator
    FROM users_contentcreatorusers
    INNER JOIN users_creatorcategories ON users_contentcreatorusers.creatorcategory1_id= users_creatorcategories.id
    INNER JOIN users_creatorcategories ON ISNULL(users_contentcreatorusers.creatorcategory2_id, NULL) = ISNULL(users_creatorcategories.id, NULL)
    INNER JOIN users_creatorcategories ON ISNULL(users_contentcreatorusers.creatorcategory3_id, NULL) = ISNULL(users_creatorcategories.id, NULL)
    WHERE approvedcreator = true
     ORDER BY currentmonitaryactioncount DESC
     LIMIT 12;
```

this sql query keeps giving me the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "browsecontentcreatorstest.py", line 115, in <module>
    lambda_handler()
  File "browsecontentcreatorstest.py", line 57, in lambda_handler
    cur.execute('''
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateAlias: table name "users_creatorcategories" specified more than once
```

I need to be able to grab the name and the icon of each of the categories a creator has.
I'm not sure how to do this without joins. And the documents I have looked at so far do not explain how to clean this up.

Comment: The modeling of the `ContentCreatorUsers` does not look very elegant. Usually a `ManyToManyField` is used for this.

Comment: the reason why it is done this way, is because a content creator can only have up to 3 categories. This is a critical part of my project. So I choose to go off pattern. If you have a better way that does not require code to ensure that the max of three has not been exceeded. I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Alias the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aliases to disambiguate the references:

```
FROM users_contentcreatorusers AS uccu
INNER JOIN users_creatorcategories AS ucc1 ON uccu.creatorcategory1_id = ucc1.id
INNER JOIN users_creatorcategories AS ucc2 ON ISNULL(uccu.creatorcategory2_id, NULL) = ISNULL(ucc2.id, NULL)
INNER JOIN users_creatorcategories AS ucc3 ON ISNULL(uccu.creatorcategory3_id, NULL) = ISNULL(ucc3.id, NULL)
```